# Python input is never True

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a trick or treat code for python but it wont work. Here is my code

```
x = str(input("Enter a letter: "))
print(treat)
if treat is True:
    print("treat")
else:
    print(trick)
```

Comment: Please take a moment to go through [formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: You should show your whole code, treat is not defined in the code you shared

Comment: Both `trick` and `treat` are not defined... so that's your problem.

Comment: Also, your title must _describe your question!_ Python coding help needed is not descriptive of the problem you're facing

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre]. What errors do you get? What have you tried to fix them? [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Im new to python that is my whole code i dont know how to define them

Comment: practically, pay special attention to any errors produced and search them first! you can create a name simply setting something equal to it (`a = "foo"`) .. however, you should familiarize yourself with the basic types (use the index at the left, each section is extremely in-depth) https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: im trying to make it so if someone enters the letter A It says treat if they enter B it says trick

Comment: You (probably) don't want [`is`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) here, you're most likely looking for `==`.  Though `treat == True` also probably isn't what you want.  What are you trying to compare the inputted letter to?

Comment: @JosephDiblasi You should put that in the question.

Comment: @JosephDiblasi `if x == 'A':` then `elif x == 'B':` and maybe an `else:` for all other inputs.

Comment: @RocketHazmat im trying to make it so if someone enters the letter A It says treat if they enter B it says trick

Comment: @RocketHazmat it says its invalid syntax

Comment: Please follow a few ***basic*** python tutorials before posting on SO.

Comment: @JosephDiblasi Can you edit the question with the code you tried, so we an can help debug the syntax error?  P.S. `str(input())` is redundant.  `input()` will always return a string.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define `trick` and `treat` before using them in the if statement

alternatively, an easier way to do this is:

```
x = str(input("Enter 1 for trick, 2 for treat: "))

if x == '1':
    print("treat")
else:
    print("trick")
```

Comment: conversion to `str` is redundant and OP asked for `"A"` and `"B"` to be what determines `"trick"` or `"treat"`, besides input shouldn't tell the user what has to be entered apparently

Comment: How do i do that im sorta new

Comment: how do i ask for a or b to determine that

Comment: the same way as this just replace with `"A"` and `"B"`, also watch a tutorial

Comment: can you link one

Comment: a tutorial to help me

Comment: @JosephDiblasi it's not like YouTube is full of them, but here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw

Comment: tysm! man this helped alot!

Comment: 1 last question, how would i make it random ie: A could be treat but the next time it be trick

Comment: use the random library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html